# C++ Classes Menu and Controller

Tags: c++, class

**Condition:**
There is a class-list (collection) of objects of another class. The main task is to create a class menu to demonstrate the functions of the controller class. The controller class includes collection robots methods.
**Algorithm**
(User selects a menu item, controller performs an action, etc.)
**Question:**
What's the best way to implement and bind the menu and controller classes?

Comment: Have you looked at `std::map` yet? It's where I would start. It's slow for a small menu, but the code is extremely simple and hard to get wrong.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Is this how it's really written? Because I don't have a clue what the problem is.